# Spring integration make asynchronous gateway wait for aggregation result

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using spring integration for processing files. I want to read file row by row, filter, convert and send to kafka. File is passed for processing via asynchronous gateway. At the end of processing I've added aggregator for 2 purposes:

- I want to wait till whole file is processed. That is, all rows properly processed have been sent to kafka and all rows that caused errors were handled by flow that reads from error channel.
- As a returned value for the gateway I want to receive aggregated results for file processing. How many rows were read from file, how many were processed without errors etc.

What I did so far, I have created aggregator that waits for file markers START and END + all processed rows. I have created custom message group that counts processed rows and also stores `replyChannel` which is taken from file START marker message and lines count which is taken from file END marker message. There is also 5s timeout set for the group. When group completes it emits message with statistics that I want and `replyChannel` header with the value taken from START marker. My understanding is that gateway awaits response on this `replyChannel`. Here is the code for message group:

```
public void add(Message<?> messageToAdd) {
        if(messageToAdd.getPayload() instanceof FileMarker) {
            FileMarker marker = (FileMarker) messageToAdd.getPayload();
            switch (marker.getMark()) {
                case START:
                    replyChannel = messageToAdd.getHeaders().get(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL);
                    break;
                case END:
                    expectedRowCount.set(marker.getLineCount());
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected file mark");
            }
        } else {
            ProcessingResult processingResult = messageToAdd.getHeaders()
                    .get(ProcessingConstants.PROCESSING_RESULT_HEADER, ProcessingResult.class);
            assert processingResult != null;
            rowCount.incrementAndGet();
            switch (processingResult) {
                case FILTERED:
                    filteredCount.incrementAndGet();
                    break;
                case PROCESSED:
                    processedCount.incrementAndGet();
                    break;
                case PROCESSING_ERROR:
                    processingErrorCount.incrementAndGet();
                    break;
                case KAFKA_ERROR:
                    kafkaErrorCount.incrementAndGet();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unrecognized processing result: " + processingResult);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is that my gateway never receives the response and waits infinitely. **How can I make asynchronous gateway wait for aggregator to emit its message and receive payload of this message as a result of gateway processing?**

Test recreating the problem can be found here https://github.com/hawk1234/spring-integration-example commit **9f121f0729d8076872e6fbdcd7b1b91ca9ea8cb4**. When you run the tests application logs are available under path **build/logs/spring-integration-example.log**. Currently test hangs as gateway never receives response. Also the whole flow is work in progress so group releases only after timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the problem. I had to manually send aggregated message to `MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL` to do this I used method `BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition#logAndReply`. Fix, as well as finished example, is available with commit **eefd5f472891ded39f363ff71ec530ada800f704**.

Answer (score 0):

> I have created custom message group that

That's something wrong.

You have to do all the required logic when you already have all the messages (including `FileMarker`) in group, standard group. There is a `MessageGroupProcessor`, which 3is called when `ReleaseStrategy` returns `true`. So, here you have all the messages for the group and you can perform all the required statistics gathering to produce a desired reply.

Your application is too complicated to digest quickly. What I see that you don't send errors to an aggregator. And that one has to be somewhere on top flow, not only in the `FileMarker` sub-flow. I mean it would be better to have an aggregator in the separate top-level flow and really send `FileMarker` directly to that one, but the rest from the `sendSuccessChannel()` and also after processing errors.

Comment: Ad 1. In regards to `MessageGroupProcessor` I know that I'm hacking a bit here. Documentation clearly states that I should only store messages in the group, but I can't do that, because I don't want to hold whole file content in memory. This approach seem to work for me, but maybe this can cause errors in some cases?

Ad 2. _What I see that you don't send errors to an aggregator_

True, flow is still work in progress, but the timeout rule works here and aggregated message can be sent to gateway.

Comment: Well, you may just convert every line `success` or `failure` for the future statistics to gather.

Comment: Good point, I will consider that. Definitely in such case I wouldn't have to write custom `MessageGroup` and modify `MessageGroupStore` - cleaner code. Though I think counting the result on the fly should be more efficient. Probably I don't even have to use `AtomicLong` since `SimpleMessageStore` synchronizes operations on the group.